# Are there any CURRENT Ruby-based OM frameworks compatible with Cassandra?

Tags: ruby, object, model, cassandra

I've looked around for a while and haven't found any good leads on production-ready Ruby-based OM frameworks I can use with Cassandra. cassandra_object looked promising, but it hasn't been updated since May 2010. I'm looking for something that's up to date.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [cassandrb](https://github.com/scrum8/cassandrb). *cough cough* It's still rough, but I think it's good enough for CRUD. Don't expect too much for complex querying though as cassandra is bad at these thing. Let me know if you found any issues. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use faunas [cassandra client](https://github.com/fauna/cassandra) (its Ruby 1.9 compatible)

Comment: This is simply a Ruby client though. I was hoping to find an OM framework that is built on top of the fauna cassandra client.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend https://github.com/data-axle/cassandra_object. We (GoTime) have been maintaining it since development stopped on the original. We have made some pretty big changes to it over the last year, to keep it in sync with Rails 3.2.

Comment: Please don't post the same answer multiple times (especially if they are promotional). If two questions are duplicate, please flag them as such.